# Tmux vi copy mode selection - character under cursor is not highlighted

Tags: zsh, tmux, highlighting

If I switch to copy mode in tmux (vi mode), and begin selecting text using `v`, the character that is directly under the cursor is never highlighted properly even though it is selected (i.e. if I copy the selection, that character shows up in the pasted text).

I want tmux to properly highlight all selected characters, including the one under the cursor just like in vim. How can I do that?

I tested it also without vi mode and with an empty `.tmux.config` file, and the same thing happens. So I don't think it has to do with my configuration.

Interestingly, the same exact behavior also happens in `zsh` when selecting text in zsh Vi mode.

Comment: If that's a block cursor, it's basically reverse-video, and since the selection would be in reverse-video, the application has to do some tweaks to keep the cursor visible, e.g., using color.  But that's terminal-dependent.

Comment: I just realized that the issue doesn't happen on my macbook (with my same config). So I suppose it is terminal dependent. Not sure what's going on tho

Answer (score 2):

From `tmux(1)` one might find

```
Ss, Se  Set or reset the cursor style ... `printf '\033[4 q'`
```

However this only applies in normal mode; the default cursor returns in
copy mode. At a guess `vim` probably issues a `tput civis`, `tput cnorm`
pair around the highlight to render the cursor temporarily invisible.
The `copy-mode-match-style` and similar do not appear to affect the
cursor in limited testing, though tmux version 3.3 added the following:

```
* Add cursor-style and cursor-colour options to set the default
  cursor style and colour.
```

This would need to be patched into older versions, or older versions
upgraded to 3.3 or higher.

`tmux` has various hooks though `after-copy-mode` is probably not
suitable as that mode must still show the cursor but hide it whenever a
highlight begins (and then show the cursor again should the user cancel
a particular highlight). One not too terrible option might be to change
the copy-mode cursor to be an underline, which leaves it mostly visible
while mostly not getting in the way of the highlight:

```
set-hook -g after-copy-mode 'set -p cursor-style underline'
```

`cursor-colour` may also be productive to fiddle around with to make it
match the `copy-mode-current-match-style` value, though I have not
experimented with that as I disable colors.